# How to have two child groups for one group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a parent group in a matrix and I want it to have 2 same level child groups:

[image: Grouping example] [image: Wanted group structure]

The problem I face is that whenever I try to add a child group to the parent group, it goes between my main group and its child group:

[image: Grouping example 2][[image: Actual group structure]

Is there a way to have it like the first example?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to right click on the lone child group, Add Group> Adjacent Above/Below.

Comment: Right-click on the FName group and chose "Add Group -> Adjacent After" (or "Adjacent Before").

Comment: Oh right! Do you mind if I change my question in order to ask if it is possible that those two adjacent child groups land in two different columns (as there is no "answer" yet)? (Let's say I want to display 2 properties of `ApplicantID` next to `FName` details, but only the main property in front of `FName2`)